# Add software to Ubuntu live usb

Tags: usb, software-installation, live-usb

In the company I work we use usb sticks with ubuntu to recover data from computers where windows can no longer access the filesystem but in many cases Ubuntu still can. At the moment we need to retrieve the computers from our customers and take them to the office to recover the data.

What I would like to know is if there is any way to add software like teamviewer to the live usb so that the engineer who visits the customer can insert the USB, boot to ubuntu live and start the recovery, open teamviewer so that we at the office can monitor the recovery and the engineer can continue his route and return later to retrieve the usb?

Concrete, I would like to create a live usb that has teamviewer (and probably other software as well) installed.

Comment: For such situation I have USB flash with **installed** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it. You can install any software, you can clone entire USB flash and so on. It is more universal, I think.

Comment: How would I go around to accomplish this?

Comment: Just install it as normal Ubuntu from installation media. But select USB-flash as target disk and do not forget to install GRUB here. I recommend fast with at least 20MB/s write speed.

Comment: Have a look at SSH if you have not already: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Persistent live Ubuntu

A good and  easy way to add some software to a live USB stick with Ubuntu is to create a persistent live system, and to install the software into it.

You can create such a system with **`mkusb`** according to the following links.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent

Please notice that in a persistent live drive

- Many valuable program packages are found in the repository **universe**, but it is not activated in [persistent] live standard Ubuntu. Make it active with

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe
  ```
- Do **not** update **& upgrade** like an installed system
- **Update** the lists according to the current content of the Ubuntu repositories

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```
- **Install programs like you would install into an installed system**, for example to install the package manager Synaptic,

  ```
  sudo apt install synaptic
  ```

  and then install the Teamviewer software you want from a debian file (like you would install it in an installed system),

  https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Installation-of-TeamViewer-on-a-Ubuntu-system/ta-p/45
- You **cannot use a new kernel and cannot use new device drivers** (for example proprietary drivers for graphics or wifi), because these are started at boot before the overlay system (of the persistent live system) is activated. If this is what you need, please use an ...

### Installed Ubuntu system in a USB stick

A good method is to create an installed system in a fast USB 3 stick. This would work like an installed system in an internal drive (but maybe slower). It will be easier if you disconnect (unplug) the internal drive before you start installing.

An installed system (compared to a persistent live system)

- is more stable and can be updated and upgraded without restrictions.
- is portable but not as portable between computers (as a persistent live system). Installed proprietary drivers may reduce portability between computers,
- should be tweaked to reduce writing to the stick in order to reduce wear of the memory cells.

You can create an installed system in a USB stick according to the following link to another question and answer at AskUbuntu (and links from my answer there),

[How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)