# How Can I create an usb persistent ubuntu from windows with bitlocker?

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb

I have a work laptop with windows 7 and BitLocker encryption.
I tried to an usb ubuntu live and no problem at all, I could use everything, than after a reboot and removed the usb key, my system started fine on windows 7.

Now I would like to create a persistent version of ubuntu on my usb key 64gb usb 3.0 . How Can I do that? I am pretty sure if i install a version from one usb to another usb will chance the bootsector and I will get an error from bitlocker.

My ideal will be:

- without usb key: normal windows as now
- with usb key start ubuntu persistent from my usb

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: You can create 1. a *persistent live* Ubuntu system or 2. an *installed Ubuntu system* in your USB pendrive. See the following links, [Persistent live Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980688/add-software-to-ubuntu-live-usb/980702#980702) and [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312) and [Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

Comment: about your third point, I already tried with success ubuntu live. I know already it, now I just want it persistent.

Comment: Then you should choose between a persistent live system and an installed system (install like into an internal drive, but in this case into an external drive). You may want to test both before deciding what is best for you. (An installed system is more difficult to create, but it is more stable and once created it is easier to keep it up to date. A persistent live system is more portable between computers.)

Comment: i am not sure about the difference between the two: persistent vs installed. I thought they were the same thing

Comment: The best way to find out is to create both systems, try them, and select the system that is best for you :-) The second best way is to search the internet for comments and discussions about both systems. You can do both ;-)